# Meaning of values in CPU tab of resource monitor on windows 8.1

Tags: resources, monitoring

[image]

(Sorry for non english character in picture. Each column is thread/CPU/average CPU)

When I open CPU tab in resource monitor on Window 8.1, I see above values.
What's the difference between CPU and average CPU?

At first, I thought average CPU means avaerag usage per core but I have 4 cores so the value should be CPU=4*avg. CPU which is not.

Please let me know the meaning of CPU and average CPU values.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**CPU**. Current percent of CPU consumption by the process, or how much of the system's processing power is being devoted to this specific process.

**Average CPU**. This is average CPU consumption by the process over the past 60 seconds. This gives you a real-time look at what's happening on the system right now and for the past minute.

http://www.techrepublic.com/blog/the-enterprise-cloud/use-resource-monitor-to-monitor-cpu-performance/